# fb graph api no response using vue

Tags: facebook, vue.js, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to make a component that shows photo's from a Facebook Photo Album. When I press the button I get the console log 'Button pressed' but nothing else shows in the console. Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
<button class="btn button" v-on:click="getFacebookPhotos">Button</button>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {}
    },
    methods: {
      getFacebookPhotos() {
        console.log('Button pressed');

        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.api('/https://www.facebook.com/pg/Caf%C3%A9-The-Piperbag-2763646256994589/photos/', 'GET', { tab: 'album', album_id: '2763679070324641/photos' }, function(response) {
            console.log('We got a response boys!'); // doesn't show
            console.log(response); // doesn't show
          })
        }
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you really mean to put a slash in front of `https`?  Is that how Facebook's graph API works?

Answer (score 0):

you have to call init function in getFaceBookPhotos function.

```
methods: {
  getFacebookPhotos() {
    console.log('Button pressed');        
    fbAsyncInit();
  },

  fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.api('https://www.facebook.com/pg/Caf%C3%A9-The-Piperbag-2763646256994589/photos/', 'GET', { tab: 'album', album_id: '2763679070324641/photos' }, function(response) {
        console.log('We got a response boys!'); // doesn't show
        console.log(response); // doesn't show
      })
  }
}
```